# Deleting a row from mysql in datagridview vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

Could someone help me with my application, I am trying to delete a row from mysql using a datagridview in vb. For some reason it either says it cant find the column named user or it just doesnt function like it should do.

Here is the code, I know its untidy and there are unused things but it shouldnt affect it.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        MySqlConnection.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim selUser As String = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
                Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE user=" & row.DataBoundItem(1).ToString
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, MySqlConnection)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from Report", MySqlConnection)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            Next
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: Fixed it now, thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: Have you checked user column in Report table?

Comment: there is a column called user in the report table, im sure

Comment: You can debug, what's in your `SqlQuery`

Comment: This is the error i got: https://puu.sh/ufb7e/1ed534e140.png

Comment: I've posted answer. Please have a look and I believe, it solves your problem in better way

Comment: https://puu.sh/ufbSw/5c0f6bfb0a.png ???

Comment: Try `row.Item(1).ToString()`

Comment: fixed now, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on error you got, I assume that it's issue of concatenation of your column name with value. So, you can avoid concatenation and sql injection(which is not avoided in your code) with using parameter based query.

Your code would be like this :

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE user= @user" 
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, MySqlConnection)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@user", row.DataBoundItem(1).ToString)) // with SqlParameter, you can pass value
```

Comment: your latest error seems more specific to vb.net. I guess, you have check `row.DataBoundItem(1)` has value or not before setting to above code

Comment: I have this: For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

Comment: Glad. you fixed. BTW, how did you fix?

Answer (score 0):

Quote your userid, you got it like

```
... WHERE user=asd
```

which is a downright SQL error.

You need it to be

```
... WHERE user='asd'
```

So, dou it as you concatenate:

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE user='" & row.DataBoundItem(1).ToString & "'"
```

or use parametrisation, as Akash KC suggested.